# Plot only the strongly connected components of a Osmnx network

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I have the following network:

```
import osmnx as ox
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import random as rd
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive')
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)
G_1 = [c for c in nx.strongly_connected_components(G)]
```

How can I plot my new G_1 network?

Comment: Please provide a working example with some example nodes, some of them strongly connected. What is not working with your code? Did you try to initialize a new graph and plot that like `G = nx.Graph(G_1)`? Or `G = nx.Graph(nx.strongly_connected_components(G))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with OSMnx by using either the [get_largest_component](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.get_largest_component) or the [induce_subgraph](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.induce_subgraph) functions, depending on your end goals. I present both options here:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
city = 'Portugal, Lisbon'
G = ox.graph_from_place(city, network_type='drive')
print(len(G)) #9699

# OPTION 1: if you only want the largest strongly connected component
Gc = ox.utils_graph.get_largest_component(G, strongly=True)
print(len(Gc)) #9503
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(Gc, node_size=0)

# OPTION 2: if you want all the strongly connected components
# first flatten the list of sets of nodes
nodes = [y for x in nx.strongly_connected_components(G) if len(x) > 1 for y in x]
Gc = ox.utils_graph.induce_subgraph(G, nodes)
print(len(Gc)) #9551
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(Gc, node_size=0)
```

EDIT: @yatu makes a good point about the size of the strongly connected components. I've edited one line above to only retain strongly connected components with more than 1 node.

Comment: But won't `nodes` be a list with all nodes? i.e your just generating the graph anew. The result of `nx.strongly_connected_components` is a list of sets, where even isolated nodes are present, they be single element sets. So your `nodes` really contains all nodes IIUC

Comment: Good point. I've edited the answer slightly accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `G_1` in your example is a list of connected components, which are sets. You'll need to generate the induced subgraphs to be able to plot them.
Say we have the graph:

[image]

With the strongly connected components:

```
list(nx.strongly_connected_components(G))
# [{3, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {6, 7}]
```

You can use [`nx.subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) to generate the induced subgraph from the connected components, and from there plot the generated graphs. Here I'm using subplots to visualize them in a grid:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import ceil

comps = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(G))
n_cols = 2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=int(ceil(len(comps)/n_cols)), 
                         ncols=n_cols, 
                         figsize=(15,8))

for comp, ax in zip_longest(comps, axes.flatten()):
    if comp is None:
        plt.box(False)
        plt.axis('off')
        continue
    G_sub = G.subgraph(comp)
    nx.draw(G_sub, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=500, ax=ax)
```

[image]